# Condition based values assignment for Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
Student = {
    'Science': [50, 80, 60, 55, 45, 90],
    'English': [45, 65, 80, 85, 75, 60],
    'Math': [50, 100, 70, 80, 75, 40],
    
}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(Student)
 
df.loc[df['Math'] > 60, "Math"] = 1
df.loc[df['Math'] < 40, "Math"] = -1
df.loc[df['Math'] >= 40, "Math"] = 0
print(df)
```

Is there a way to assign 0/1/-1 values based on the range of grades scored for all the subjects at once?
For instance, if the grades are above 40 but below 60 it is 0. If above 60, it is 1 else it is -1.

It is a fully numeric data frame.

Comment: or `df['Math'] = pd.cut(df['Math'], [-np.inf, 40, 60, np.inf], labels=[-1, 0, 1])`